# How to uniquely identify a field in Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle database connected to .Net application.

Let's say I have a ***Table : MyTable*** in the Database with Fields ***A and B***.

And another view like : ***MyView : Select A from MyTable;***

For some application reasons, is there any way to check or to know that the **Field A** returned in **MyView** is exactly the same **Field A** in table **MyTable ?**

I'm not talking here about records. I'm talking about fields only. So no matter what is stored in the table or returned by the view.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "is exactly the same"? Do you mean "the column in the view reflects the column by the same name in the stored table"? If so, then the only way to know that is to examine the view definition (the statement that creates the view). In your case, the column is the same in this sense.

Comment: This is literally impossible to do with in a general case.  As an extreme example, what if the view looks like `create view myView as select function randomly_return_one_value(A, B) from ...`?.  A realistic, but still complex example, is what if the view uses aliases?  Then you'd need a parser to tell where the column came from, which is incredibly difficult in Oracle SQL.  So this question depends on the exact details of your special case.  Can you guarantee the views are constructed a specific way?  Are you willing to live with a solution that's only 50% accurate?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are probably asking the wrong question [**What is the XY problem?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)